# Howto for simple pipe without shell escape in perl?

Tags: perl, security, shell

My perl cgi program needs to pass an arbitrary latex math expression, provided by an anonymous untrusted malicious web user, into a (trusted) phantomjs script that runs mathjax to obtain SVG.  Think that I want to do

```
use Perl6::Slurp;
my $svg= slurp( my $fname, "mathjax-script.js '$not_trusted_expr' |");
```

in many scripts I had written in the past, I could sanitize $not_trusted_expr into containing only characters from my approved list, but LaTeX is itself too expressive to make this a feasible approach.  My user can provide a $not_trusted_expr that can contain literally anything---incl \' itself---and for perfectly good reasons.

So, I need to be absolutely certain that there are no ways that any shell escape characters are interpreted along the way in the travel of my characters to my mathjax-script.js .

Do I read the slurp doc correctly in believing that

```
my $svg=slurp( "-|", "mathjax-script.js", $not_trusted_expr );
```

is the complete solution to this problem, because it means that the shell is never even invoked?

/iaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Perl6::Slurp::slurp` wraps the builtin [`open`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#open) function, and the `... -|, $cmd, @args` syntax will pass arguments directly to the system `execvp` function (on Unixy systems, as the `Perl6::Slurp` doc allude to).